# Change mnemonic for Menu on Menubar from default Alt to Ctrl?

Tags: java, mnemonics

I want to use Ctrl instead of Alt for mnemonics of a menu on a menubar. I think it involves using a setAccelerator.

```
formatMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
sizeMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_X);
styleMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Z);
```

This is initalised code which allows me to open the menu but only when I use Alt.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
formatMenu.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

EDIT: this won't work unless formatMenu is a JMenuItem; for JMenu, setting an accelerator seems not supported natively (at least i have not found any result). A workaround is to implement get/setAccelerator for a menu, like in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909851/how-to-set-an-accelerator-for-a-jmenu-sub-menu) (there it's done for a submenu, but you can modify to suite your needs).

So just do something like the accepted answer there does:

```
JMenu formatMenu = new JMenu("Format Menu") {
    private KeyStroke accelerator;

    @Override
    public KeyStroke getAccelerator() {
        return accelerator;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAccelerator(KeyStroke keyStroke) {
        KeyStroke oldAccelerator = accelerator;
        this.accelerator = keyStroke;
        repaint();
        revalidate();
        firePropertyChange("accelerator", oldAccelerator, accelerator);
    }
};
                formatMenu.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

Comment: java.lang.Error: setAccelerator() is not defined for JMenu.  Use setMnemonic() instead.

Comment: corrected my answer - my bad, was not attentive that you were working with JMenu, not JMenuItem

Comment: did you also add the mnemonics as well as the code above with the accelerator?

Comment: i used the following:
    JMenu formatMenu = new JMenu("Format Menu") {
           private KeyStroke accelerator;

           
    public KeyStroke getAccelerator() {
    return accelerator;
    }
    
    public void setAccelerator(KeyStroke keyStroke) {
    KeyStroke oldAccelerator = accelerator;
    this.accelerator = keyStroke;
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    firePropertyChange("accelerator", oldAccelerator,         accelerator);
    }
    };
formatMenu.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));
formatMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

Comment: i still cant get the menus to use ctrl for mnemonics instead of alt